# Why could \usepackage{Sweave} be affecting my graphics scaling?

Tags: graphics, scaling, sweave

I'm using Sweave to produce a large, multi part academic thesis. I had neglected to specify `\usepackage{Sweave}` in my preamble, but everything was working fine until I added some verbatim output from R. The latex compiler threw some errors that keyed me in to my omission of the `\usepackage{Sweave}` directive.

When I added `\usepackage{Sweave}` to my preamble, the verbatim output worked fine, but many images in my document suddenly got scaled strangely. The seem to keep their height, but their width was expanded.

Generally I scale my images by specifying height, such as: `\includegraphics[height=1.5in]{graphicName}`. If I instead specify `\includegraphics[height=1.5in, keepaspectratio=true]{graphicName}` I get the expected behavior. I've never needed this additional flag before.

Why is Sweave changing the [default behavior](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Importing_Graphics#Including_graphics) of `\includegraphics{}`?

Apologies for the lack of a minimal reproducible example here, but my document structure is pretty complex at this point.

Comment: Are you using the `graphicx` package? Sweave.sty loads that package http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/share/texmf/tex/latex/Sweave.sty . If so, you could try ensuring `graphicx` loads before Sweave.

Comment: I am using `graphicx`, and its include statement is above Sweave's.

Comment: Perhaps you should try `knitr` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sweave style sets the default figure width.

In svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/share/texmf/tex/latex/Sweave.sty the relevant line is:

`\setkeys{Gin}{width=0.8\textwidth}`

This can be turned off using the `nogin` package option:

`\usepackage[nogin]{Sweave}`

Comment: Thanks, but what's `Gin`? Should I know this name from elsewhere? Seems a bit cryptic.

Comment: `Gin` is a set of keys in the `graphicx` package that can be set to control figure sizes without changing each `\includegraphics` command: https://engineering.purdue.edu/~mark/puthesis/missing-files/graphicx.sty